# Evaluate $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{|dz|}{|z-a|^2}$ using Cauchy's Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

**Question:** Evaluate $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{|dz|}{|z-a|^2}$ using Cauchy's Theorem.

**My attempt:** So, Cauchy's theorem for derivatives tells us that if $f$ is holomorphic in an open set $\Omega$, and $D$ is a disc with boundary $C$ such that $D$ and $C$ are contained in $\Omega$, we have, for any point $z \in D$,

$$f^{(n)}(z) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{\zeta}{(\zeta - z)^{n+1}}\ d\zeta.$$

Let $f(z) = |z|$, then $f'(z) = z/|z|$, thus we have:
$$f'(a) = \frac{a}{|a|}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|= 1}\frac{|z|}{|z-a|^2}\ dz.$$

this is really close to the integral I want to evaluate, but it obviously isn't quite right. I'm also getting confused because of the absolute value of $|dz|$ in the problem statement - how can I handle that?

Thanks.

Comment: since it is $\int_{|z|=1}$ I consider $z = e^{i\theta}$, $dz = i e^{i \theta} d \theta$ and $|dz| = |d \theta| = d \theta$, while $|z-a|^2 = |e^{i \theta} -a|^2 = (e^{i \theta} -a)(e^{-i \theta} - \overline{a})$, hence $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{|dz|}{|z-a|^2} = \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d\theta}{(e^{i \theta} -a)(e^{-i \theta} - \overline{a})} = \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{i e^{i \theta} d\theta}{ie^{i \theta }(e^{i \theta} -a)(e^{-i \theta} - \overline{a})} = \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z(z-a)(1/z-\overline{a})} = \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(z-a)(1-\overline{a}z )} = \ldots$

Comment: and when you write "$f(z)$ is holomorphic on $|z| < 1$, let $f(z) = |z|$"  it is awful ! $f(z) = |z|$ is everything but holomorphic ! would you prove the Cauchy theorem(s) first, please ? (and that holomorphic $\implies$ analytic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $|z|^2=z\bar z=1$, $\bar z=z^{-1}$ and $|dz|=\frac{1}{iz}dz$.  Then, we have

$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{|z-a|^2}\,|dz|=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{i(z-a)(1-az)}\,dz$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: This was very useful, and I managed to solve the problem using your hint, thank you! It took me a while to work out the solution, and I had forgotten to accept your answer afterwards - my apologies.

Comment: Poppy, please to hear that this was useful!  And no apology necessary.  -Mark